# How to enble and disable the button in oracle apex if we want to give condition?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5

How to enable and disable the button in oracle apex if we want to give condition?

Answer (score 8):

1. Use **Condition** of button properties. In this case button will be visible or invisible.
2. Create **Dynamic Action** and use **Action:Disable or Enable**
3. Create **Dynamic Action** and use **Add Class or Remove Class**. For class name put **apex_disabled**
4. Create **Dynamic Action** and use **Execute JavaScript Code**. Use static ID for the button(for example - **btn**) and add class via JavaScript:
   `$("#btn").addClass("apex_disabled");`
    `$("#btn").removeClass("apex_disabled");`
5. Create **Dynamic Action** and use **Execute JavaScript Code**. Use static ID for the button(for example - **btn**)

   `$("#btn").attr("disabled", true);`
     `$("#btn").attr("disabled", false);`
   Just use conditions to meet your needs.

Comment: Hi, can this be done for some columns as well? In my grid few columns in each row are disabled, but the sequence could be any. ex: 1st and 2nd column in row 1, and 3rd and 4th in row 2. Can this be achieved?