# How to enable submit button based on validate button in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-20.2

I am searching for this every where no one is able to help me.

Only this is the one hope left for me

**Below is my scenario and components I have used**

```
*  1 file browse button - To select file 
*  2 buttons 
     first  button 1 is for validating 
     second button 2 is for submitting
```

**Below is my GUI designed in Oracle APEX**

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hOcM.png)

**Note :**

*On page load my submit button is disabled initially  - it cannot be clicked.
On that submit button I have written PL/SQL code in backend as dynamic action*

**So my aim is to achieve step 3**

Step 1 : I will choose file using file browse button

Step 2 : After selecting my file I will click **VALIDATE** button.

Once I click on validate button my dynamic action will get trigger which is written in `JavaScript`.

This Java script checks the file choosen is empty or not and return `true` or `false`

**Sample code :**

```
  if ( file is empty ) 
  {
    return false     
  }
  else
  {
    return true
  }
```

Step 3 : Once my Validate return true my `Submit` button should get enabled
and After its enabled and once I click on submit button my PL/SQL code should run

I ask every one over YouTube no one as respond me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enble and disable the button in oracle apex if we want to give condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445197/how-to-enble-and-disable-the-button-in-oracle-apex-if-we-want-to-give-condition)

Comment: @Boris Serafimov  : Can you provide me your input for above question

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, I'd **remove** the "Validate" button entirely.

- modify validation so that it doesn't return TRUE/FALSE, but e.g. Error Text so that - if file is empty - validation displays appropriate message and stops further execution
- leave the "Submit" button as is; it should just *submit*

  - if validation failed, nothing would be submitted
  - otherwise, it would

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep the "Validate" button, create dynamic action on it with several steps:

- see if that JavaScript can set hidden item's value to e.g. "true" or "false" (I can't assist with that, I'm not good at JavaScript at all) (that's "Set Value" dynamic action) (initially, on page load, set it to "false")
- presume you managed to do that; next dynamic action step would be "Show" which shows the button if "Client side condition" is met, and that's if hidden item's value is "true"
- the next step is "Hide"; its "Client side condition" is just the opposite, i.e. if hidden item's value is "false" (make it run at page initialization as well, so that the "Submit" button is initially hidden)

That would be it, I guess.